# Scraping complete web site for data within specific div tag where url includes string

Tags: php, mysql, csv, screen-scraping

I own a webshop and one of my suppliers is kind enough to give me a CSV file with product model numbers, price and title but they can't give me database dumps including their product descriptions. I am allowed to scrape the product descriptions though - the question is how?

```
All URLs include the model number like "title-of-product-MN-504-1.htm"
The descriptions are inside a <div> tag like "<div id="description"> Bla bla bla <other tag>bla bla </other tag> bla bla </div>"
```

Lets say I have all the model numbers in a csv file or MySQL table - how can I save the descriptions associated with the model number in the URL(also located within another div tag if that's easier)?

To sum up - input will be model numbers from a csv or MySQL table and the output should be a MySQL table(or csv) with the model numbers and the description from the div tag on individual pages. 
I'm considering the following tools but I'm unsure how to connect them to do what I want: wget, cURL and [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You could use this http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/ and use this particular property: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/classreferences/index.html, then to find the description : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493236/extract-string-between-html-tags-in-php . Actually the last URL seems to be enough.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the right way to do it - but how do I only crawl the urls that contain the model number string from the list/array containing the model numbers? How about: 1) Crawl the site for URL's containing the model number (how should I do this?) 2) Use phpcrawl and php simple DOM parser to get the descriptions 3) Save results to MySQL

Comment: See my answer, little hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/ and use this particular property: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de//classreferences/index.html, then to find the description : [Extract string between html tags in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493236/extract-string-between-html-tags-in-php)

As for your requirement of finding the modelnumber in URL's found on the crawled page you could use the following property: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/classreferences/index.html

If you'd index the CSV file you got from them and index their site; I'd do the following

You build up a list of all the modelnumbers you need to get the description of.

1. Crawl their frontpage to start the process. *gather URLs, add to visitlist*
2. Visit every URL in your list that matches the modelnumber, get description, remove the model from the list. *gather URLs, add to visitlist*
3. Back to step 2 - repeat untill there's no more model on your list

As for how to get the URLs with the modelnumber in them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Something like this, I leave the implementation up to you:

```
foreach($list_of_urls as $url) {
    foreach($list_of_modelnumbers as $model) {
        if(strpos($url, $model)) {
            $list_of_urls_to_crawl[] = $url; 
   /* you can also remove the $model, but I already wrote it in a foreach loop */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can clear the `$list_of_urls` and append the new ones from the crawler results :)

```
foreach($list_of_urls_to_crawl as $url) {
     //Set $crawler, let him go, get your description etc.

     foreach($crawler->links_found as $url) {
         $list_of_urls[] = $url;
     }
}
```

And place it in a grand `while($still_need_descriptions)` loop.

Comment: If you regularly get a new file and/or things are regularly changed you'd better store the URL in a database and do something with that data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly the sort of help I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't like http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/, you could use [PHP-Spider](https://mvdbos.github.io/php-spider/).

It would be as simple as writing a custom URL discoverer based on the CSV
and then parsing the crawled pages with XPath queries. See the example on https://mvdbos.github.io/php-spider/. The only thing you would need to change is the Discoverer class that is added to the Spider. Assuming you  know how the URLs are built, it could look like this:

```
class CsvModelNumberDiscoverer implements Discoverer
{
    protected $modelNumbersAndTitles = array();

    public function __construct(array $modelNumbersAndTitles)
    {
        $this->modelNumbersAndTitles = $modelNumbersAndTitles;
    }

    public function discover(Spider $spider, Resource $document)
    {
        $urls = array();
        foreach ($this->modelNumbersAndTitles as $number => $title) {
            $urls[] = 'http://example.com/' . $title . '-MN-' . $number . '.htm';
        }
        return $urls;
    }
}
```

The code where you run the spider would look like this:

```
$spider = new Spider('http://www.example.com');
$spider->addDiscoverer(new CsvModelNumberDiscoverer($modelNumbersAndTitles);
$result = $spider->crawl();
```

Finally, you could get the descriptions from the results like this:

```
foreach ($result['queued'] as $resource) {
    $modelNo = $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath("div[@id='modelNo']")->text();
    $description = $resource->getCrawler()->filterXpath("div[@id='description']")->text();
}
```

If you don't know how the URLs are built, you would have spider the whole site (as in AmazingDreams' answer) and use the discoverer to match URLs to the list of model numbers. It take more time though.

Full disclosure: I wrote [PHP-Spider](https://mvdbos.github.io/php-spider/).

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the html code using

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/title-of-product-MN-504-1.htm');
```

Then you use the html code with the php dom parser, to get the value of the exact elements you need.